# Solving differential equations: Prove that any term which is in the complementary function $y_c$ need not be included in the trial solution $y_p$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I prove that any term which is in the complementary function $y_c$ need not be included in the trial solution $y_p$?

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Please explain the terminology "complementary function" and "trial function".

Comment: Complementary function:
the part of the general solution of a linear differential equation which is the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation obtained by substituting zero for the terms not containing the dependent variable. And the trial function is what you use to find the solution for the non-homogeneous part

Comment: Hint:Show that the coefficients of this term will always add to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $y_c$ is a soluton to the homogeneous solution, and $y_p$ is a solution to the in-homogenous equation therefore
$y_c$ will not contribute to the inhomogenous part of the equation.

If your equation is in-homogeneous then the solutions of the homogeneous equation which are $y_c$  will not satisfy the in-homogeneous equation so they will not be part of your $y_p$